# Internet explorer 11 freezing if the dropdown menu of the column filter is open

Tags: internet-explorer-11, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Please open the following example in internet explorer 11: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-dragging/#example-simple-unmanaged

[image: ag-grid-example]

Has anyone had this problem? Or any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: I tried it in Win10 20H2 and found that it also gets stuck when opening this dropdown. It just shows not responding, even though I waited a long time. In addition, IE will no longer be supported soon, I recommend that you could use a modern browser,like Chrome or Microsoft Edge.

Comment: I need to support Internet Explorer 11. I'm looking for a hint to look for the error in the right place in ag-grid.

Comment: I did a simple test of it again and I found that it works when the filter field is entered before the dropdown is selected. Here is a [sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY6Fb.png).

Comment: Problem will be investigated by ag-grid https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/4906#issuecomment-1042809602